# Does Hearthstone have raids or coop multiplayer?

Tags: hearthstone

According to [Cooptimus](http://www.co-optimus.com/game/3213/pc/hearthstone-heroes-of-warcraft.html), Hearthstone is 2-player coop, and specifically

> Players use their characters and cards to fight against "raid boss" characters together.

However, I've played for a few hours now and haven't found any way to play anything other than 1v1.

Does Hearthstone really have coop, or *any* other multiplayer mode besides 1v1?

Comment: I think they might refer to the upcoming raid mode, where players can venture into Naxxramas and fight raid bosses. There have also been notes to a 2v2 mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in time there is no co-op mode. Co-op mode was asked [about on a beta survey](http://www.vg247.com/2013/11/25/hearthstone-survey-hints-at-potential-new-features-co-op-raids-mentioned/), indicating that Blizzard is considering it for the future but it is not confirmed as an upcoming feature.

Answer (score 3):

HearthStone is (currently) a 1v1 game - *there is no co-op or 'raid' feature*. The description featured on "Cooptimus" is incorrect. Feel free to  read this Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearthstone:_Heroes_of_Warcraft which states "Each Hearthstone battle is a 1vs1 match between two opponents".

Answer (score 1):

Currently hearthstone is limited to 1v1 battles.

Blizzard has announced an adventure inspired by WoW's Naxxramas (http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Curse_of_Naxxramas) to be released this summer, but it'll be a single player against bosses played by a computer